# $\{T_n\}$ Folner $\implies \{S_n\} = \{\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}T_k\}$ Folner?

Tags: group-theory, amenability

Given an countable amenable group $G$, let $\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Folner sequence for $G$, i.e., $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{|gT_n \Delta T_n|}{|T_n|} = 0$, for every $g \in G$. Now, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider $S_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^n T_k$. My question is whether or not $\{S_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Folner sequence.

Obviously, if $\{T_n\}$ is increasing, the answer is yes, but I am not being able to prove the case when $\{T_n\}$ is not increasing and I don't even know if this is true.

What I did so far is: given $g \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{|gS_n \Delta S_n|}{|S_n|} &\leq \frac{|\bigcup_{k=1}^n(gT_k \Delta T_k)|}{|S_n|}\\
&\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|gT_k \Delta T_K|}{|S_n|}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|gT_k \Delta T_K|}{|S_n|}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|gT_k \Delta T_K|}{|T_k|}
\end{align*}
and I know that what is inside the sum goes to zero, but this does not help me (or at least I don't see how it could help me).

Does someone know how to prove it or have a counterexample?

Comment: You need $G$ to be countable, otherwise it has no Følner sequence.

Comment: Ok. But assuming $G$ countable and assuming that $\{T_n\}$ is a Folner sequence, can you decide whether or not the sequence $\{S_n\}$ is Folner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are counterexamples.

Define in $\mathbf{Z}$, $F_n=[0,\sqrt{n}]\cup\{n^2\}$ (in the segment I implicitly intersect with $\mathbf{Z}$). It's Følner, because adding the singleton is negligible. But $F'_n=\bigcup_{k\le n}F_n=[0,\sqrt{n}]\cup\{k^2:k\le n\}$ is not Følner because for $k>n^{1/4}$ we have $k^2\in F'_n$ but $k^2+1\notin F'_n$, so $\frac{|F'_n|\Delta|F'_n+1|}{|F'_n|}$ even tends to 1.

On the other hand, it's true (in every group) if the $F_n$ are pairwise disjoint (use that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are real sequences with $a_n\ge 0$ and $b_n\ge 1$ and $a_n/b_n\to 0$, then $\sum a_n/\sum b_n\to 0$).

Comment: (I could equally define $F_n=[0,\sqrt{n}]\cup\{2n\}$.)